# Error in finding an element with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, element, webautomation

[image]

I want to find this element (see picture) using Python Selenium. I tried copying xpath and other but it always shows me element not found. How should I find this element?

**My code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ow284').click()  
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ow430"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]').click()
```

**The error message:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="ow284"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.183)
```

*Text copied from the image for better view:*

```
<li jscontroller="x5l08e" jsmodel="dSSknb;PTCFbe;xeYtDf;" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;uwjiC:rcuQ6b;SU3oCd:s5WlDe;IKbv3d:rcuQ6b;wuANJc:.CLIENT" class="tfGBod Pedc8e OlXwxf tUJKGd bFjUmb-Wvd9Cc BgWeDc u0dx8e AZd1I J1HJOd TIunU ndcsBf" guidedhelpid="classworkTopicListGh" data-dom-id="221284414334|1|RH7Ihb[266]" data-draggable-item-id="221284414334" data-has-focusable-child="" data-stream-item-id="221284414334" data-expandable-row-id="221284414334" data-submission-id="2" data-include-submission-materials="false" data-stream-item-type="multiple-choice" data-include-stream-item-materials="false" data-controller-loaded="true" id="ow284" __is_owner="true"><div jsname="haAclf"><div class="jWCzBe QRiHXd idtp4e u73Apc" jsaction="click:h5M12e; mousedown:RlITDf" jsname="tdoU3e"><div class="SFCE1b" jsname="rQC7Ie" tabindex="0" role="button" data-focusable-child="" aria-label="Expand 7 November 2020" aria-expanded="false"></div><div class="D3ZbAb"><div jscontroller="RO34pe" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;voP7ud:rcuQ6b" data-controller-loaded="true" class="oC328b QRiHXd iobNdf vUBwW bFjUmb-Wvd9Cc C2NJgb m1PbN"><div class="PazDv">Completed Question</div><svg focusable="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class=" NMm5M hhikbc"><path d="M19 2H5a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h4l3 3 3-3h4c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16H5V4h14v14z"></path><path d="M11 15h2v2h-2zm1-8c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2 0 2-3 1.75-3 5h2c0-2.25 3-2.5 3-5 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4S8 6.79 8 9h2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="xVnXCf QRiHXd"><div class="lio3ib"><div class="kByKEb QRiHXd asQXV"><span class="YVvGBb UzbjTd">7 November 2020</span><div class="seqYL QRiHXd" jscontroller="bjXHU" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;Ts0WYd:rcuQ6b" jsmodel="xvu37b" data-controller-loaded="true" data-type="2" data-visibility="2" data-stream-item-id="221284414334"></div></div><div class="WZkEbf YVvGBb dDKhVc">Due Nov 7, 12:59 PM</div></div><span class="nZCyt T3FW5d dDKhVc" jsmodel="PTCFbe" data-stream-item-id="221284414334"><div jscontroller="pWi3Yd" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;CPX6Je:rcuQ6b;wuANJc:rcuQ6b" class="YVvGBb YglcOe "></div></span><div class="wCDkmf T3FW5d YVvGBb dDKhVc">Due Nov 7, 12:59 PM</div></div><div class="WyjGac T3FW5d" data-focus-id="221284414334-menu"><div jscontroller="sQN9ue" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;uwjiC:rcuQ6b;IKbv3d:rcuQ6b;ymHzQd:rcuQ6b;yyauTb:rcuQ6b;wJx4ze:rcuQ6b;aWRkAb:OA5Drb" jsmodel="I8BbUd" data-stream-item-id="221284414334" data-reordering-enabled="true" class=" lGm3nb" data-guided-help-id="classworkActionMenuGh"><div jsshadow="" role="button" class="U26fgb JRtysb WzwrXb I12f0b K2mXPb" jscontroller="iSvg6e" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;keydown:I481le" jsname="LgbsSe" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-dynamic="true" data-alignright="true" aria-label="Question options"><div class="NWlf3e MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><span jsslot="" class="MhXXcc oJeWuf"><span class="Lw7GHd snByac"><svg focusable="false" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class=" NMm5M"><path d="M12 8c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2s-.9-2-2-2-2 .9-2 2 .9 2 2 2zm0 2c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2zm0 6c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2s.9 2 2 2 2-.9 2-2-.9-2-2-2z"></path></svg></span></span></div></div></div></div><div class="S9CVKb a2rP" jsname="xILaRb" style="height: 0px;"><div class="UW3s6d"><div class="grsMub"><div class="wvNVNd"><div class="vGGYOe YVvGBb dDKhVc"><span>Posted Nov 7</span></div><div class="HSe5uf"><span jscontroller="tM54Ef" class="UhYXkc ZnNi8e" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;voP7ud:rcuQ6b;wuANJc:rcuQ6b;uwjiC:rcuQ6b" data-submission-id="2" data-render-simple-labels="true"><span class="u7S8tc YVvGBb"><span class="">Turned in</span></span><span class="E70Hue neggzd" aria-hidden="true">Estigfend</span></span></div></div><div class="IMcm2d"><div class="bqKF7d pco8Kc "><html-blob><span class="NjE5zd">Are You Present?</span></html-blob></div></div></div><div class="pvbZV"><div jscontroller="AwTMWd" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;uwjiC:rcuQ6b;KtPeHe:rcuQ6b;IKzbTb:Yo3LPb;wuANJc:.CLIENT" data-parent-id="PTCFbe" data-mode="5" data-copies-only="false" data-single-thumbnail-list="false" data-show-originality-analyses="false" data-forms-only="false" jsmodel="PTCFbe" data-include-stream-item-materials="true" data-stream-item-id="221284414334" class="DuMice  fIXHld RDCsQc"></div></div><div class="uStMnd"><div jscontroller="nEKTNb" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;uwjiC:nPtwgc;wuANJc:rcuQ6b;voP7ud:rcuQ6b;sPvj8e:Wk62Wc(cnAzRb);JIbuQc:vv2cgd(M2UYVd)" class="bs9m7d"><div jsname="dGx3Pe" class="jeczbd"></div><div jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" role="radiogroup" class="lLfZXe fnxRtf" jsname="cnAzRb"><span jsslot="" role="presentation" jsname="bN97Pc" class="H2Gmcc tyNBNd"><label class="NtlN8c xBIR3c Uy7ePe YRdPTb" role="presentation"><div class="d7L4fc bJNwt  gtyeSe"><div class="Od2TWd hYsg7c N2RpBe RDPZE" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" aria-label="Yes" aria-disabled="true" data-value="Yes" role="radio" aria-checked="true" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="2"><div class="x0k1lc MbhUzd"></div><div class="uyywbd"></div><div class="vd3tt"><div class="AB7Lab Id5V1"><div class="rseUEf nQOrEb"></div></div></div></div></div><span class="hHhDYc snByac">Yes</span></label><label class="NtlN8c xBIR3c Uy7ePe YRdPTb" role="presentation"><div class="d7L4fc bJNwt  gtyeSe"><div class="Od2TWd hYsg7c RDPZE i9xfbb" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" aria-label="No" aria-disabled="true" data-value="No" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="2"><div class="x0k1lc MbhUzd"></div><div class="uyywbd"></div><div class="vd3tt"><div class="AB7Lab Id5V1"><div class="rseUEf nQOrEb"></div></div></div></div></div><span class="hHhDYc snByac">No</span></label></span></div><div class="heSgkb"><div jsshadow="" role="button" class="uArJ5e UQuaGc Y5sE8d CG2qQ RDPZE" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef" jsname="M2UYVd" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;"><div class="Fvio9d MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="e19J0b CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="l4V7wb Fxmcue"><span class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac">Turn in</span></span></div></div></div></div><div jscontroller="IGT0cf" jsaction="rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b;Ts0WYd:rcuQ6b;JIbuQc:Yh7j1c(PlbUX)" jsmodel="xvu37b" data-type="2" data-visibility="2" guidedhelpid="commentsdialogGH" class="yVyYEc LhPqk" data-stream-item-id="221284414334" data-with-icon="false" data-show-add-comments-link="false"></div></div><div class="O9YpHb QRiHXd" data-focus-id="221284414334-view"><div jsshadow="" role="presentation" class="uArJ5e UQuaGc kCyAyd l3F1ye oxacD" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef" jsname="PWjRFc" aria-disabled="false"><a class="IrxBzb TpQm9d" href="/c/MTkxMjc4MjE0MTY0/mc/MjIxMjg0NDE0MzM0/details"><div class="Fvio9d MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div><div class="e19J0b CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="l4V7wb Fxmcue"><span class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac">View question</span></span></a></div></div></div></div></li>
```

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(., '7 November 2020')]")`

Comment: @JaSON It does select but it's selecting the next element. Can you please tell me what you used here so that I can learn from googling? Thank you.

Comment: and is there any other way to find the element?  It's not working correctly

Comment: Which element do you want to select exactly? And which element is currently selected? Also I'm not sure I understand the question *what you used here*...